# Python script failing on Ubuntu but working on windows

Tags: python, windows, list, ubuntu

I have a script that fetches sone html doc from some website( using requests)

The script looks through the recieved document using Beautifulsoup module,and extracts links which are again used to fetch some data using requests.Once response is recieved,an list item is returned with some exctracted data.

```
   from requests import get
   from bs4 import Beautifulsoup
   response1 = get(url1)
   #From response1 I use beautifulsoup to find links and loop through them
   For link in foundlinks:
    response 2 = get(link)
    #I use beautifulsoup to exctract more links again
    #I use the exctracted link again
    For final_link in recieved_links
     data  = get(final_link)
       #I use beautifulsoup to find data and append to a global list
```

This is a logic demonstration of how my code looks(its huge I can't paste it here entirely).
Do,on windows in terminal when i execute the script everything works okay.However,on ubuntu,i get varying errors when i rerun the script.
The varying error varies interms of location of error only.The error is "List out of index error" which occurs just after line5 in my logic example and other times its on line 10.
It should also be noted that I get different those varying errors Even when I have not changed any part of my code(I only re execution)

What could be the issue?
What makes everything abit hard to understand for me is why I get different errors yet I have not changed the code  at all?

Comment: Your pseudocode doesn't use list indexing so there isn't much to go on. Does your real code index a list on those lines? If so, you could `print(len(mylist), myindex)` to get a first hint of the overflow, or simply `if len(mylist) <= myindex: print useful data here`.

Comment: Maybe your Ubuntu has some kind of network problem. Try opening your links a few times in your browser under Ubuntu and see if it shows some error.